# Can I push file to multiple devices using one adb command?

Tags: android, adb

as I got 10 android devices connected through Wi-Fi, is there any way to push same file to them in one command?

Comment: No, but you can write a script using bash/python/your-favourite-scripting-language.

Comment: This is also helpful dealing with multiple connected devices: https://gist.github.com/dtmilano/4537110

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR>1 && $2 == "device" {system("adb -s " $1 " shell date")}' < <(adb devices)
```

this example runs `date` on all connected devices, you can replace it with your `push`.

`xargs` can also be used but previous command is simpler.